# How to calculate the sample variance of aggregated data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, missing-data, likelihood, pooling

I have dataset where I am only seeing the aggregated data. Assume that there is an underlying random variable, $p$. The sample data is of the form $P_i = \sum^{n_i}_{j=1} p_{ij}$ with $i=1..N$.  The individual $n_i$ are randomly distributed. I would like to estimate the variance of $p$ from this dataset.

In my case, about one third of the data has $n_i = 1$, so a simple approach is to use only this subset of the data, and estimate the sample variance of $p$ directly from it.  However, this is discarding two thirds of the data. Is there a better method of calculating the sample variance using all of the data?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the sample variance of the groups.

Comment: I am not so sure that you cannot recover the variance. My example above of choosing all groups with $n_i =1$ does provide a method, although only for data sets that have samples with $n_i = 1$.  Extending this idea further, one approach would be to divide all the samples into groups with the same value of $n_i$.  You can calculate the sample variance of each group. The shape of the graph of sample variance versus $n_i$ must have some information about the underlying variance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can solve this with likelihood methods if we, in addition, can assume the original individual observations are iid normal. So suppose you have 
$$
  x_{i,1},x_{i,2},\dots, x_{i,n_i} \sim \text{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)
$$ independently, but you do only know
$$
   \bar{x}_i \sim \text{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n_i), \quad, i=1,2\dots,m
$$
where some of the (known) $n_i$'s are equal to 1.

Write the likelihood function, take logarithms and you find the loglikelihood function as 
$$
\ell = \sum_{i=1}^m \cdot \log \sqrt{n_i} - \frac12 \log (2\pi\sigma^2) -\frac12 n_i \left(\frac{\bar{x}_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2
$$
differentiating this with respect to $\mu$, setting equal to zero gives the likelihood equation for $\mu$, with solution
$$
\hat{\mu}=\frac{\sum n_i \bar{x}_i}{\sum n_i}
$$
that is, the solution is the weighted least squares estimator.

To find an estimator for the variance $\sigma^2$, differentiate the loglikelihood function with respect to $\sigma^2$: First write
$$
S^2 = \sum n_i (\bar{x}_i -\hat{\mu})^2
$$
Then the concentrated loglikelihood can be written
$$
\ell^* = \frac12\sum \log(n_i) -\frac{m}{2}\log(2\pi \sigma^2) - \frac12\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}
$$
differentiating, setting equal to zero and solving gives the estimator of the variance as
$$
\hat{\sigma^2} = \frac{S^2}{m}
$$
The same approach can be used if the parent distribution is something other than normal.

Comment: This certainly gives an elegant final answer.  I have upvoted it, but am looking for a solution that does not assume a particular distribution.  Or perhaps one that deduces the parent distribution from the aggregated data, then applies the maximum likelihood method to that calculated distribution.

Comment: As long as you only want the standard deviation, the formulas above can be developed without reliance on the normal distribution. A more important assumption is independence!  An interesting additional answer is how much you loose by estimating the variance in this way, compared to having the complete data.  I will add something about that to the answer when I have time.

Comment: I was assuming i.i.d.  Are you saying the final answer is the same, irregardless of the actual distribution?  That would be very neat.

Comment: The "m" in the denominator suggests that this estimator is biased.  Is there a way to redo the math so that it's unbiased as well as consistent?